# Android: HorizontalScrollBar needs snap to next item even with short scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/level1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/level1"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            />
         </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I am having is when I scroll, if it is not long enough, it gets stuck in the middle (between imageviews). Is there a way I can have it scroll all the way to the next item instead? Am I even using the right tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by Using ViewPager & Fragments instead of HSB.

Answer (score -1):

try using wrap_content in the width of HorizontalScrollView. I hope this helps you. BestRegards

Comment: No help, I am not sure you understand my question I am trying to scroll the whole image view and snap to the middle of the next one... (sorry for the thumbs down but no help)

Comment: Hi, don't worry about it, we are here for helping. Have you tried another way to make that? if I understand fine, you need to put some images in an horizontal layout and then use a scroll for look all of them. May be you can use a fragment, this doesn't exactly use a scroll but you can swap between fragments. Look this documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: I think you are on the right track I need to look at using ViewPager of HSB I think...

Comment: Ok, if you need more help, you can comment. BestRegards